# Using CSS how to have row of tables followed by row of tables

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have an Array of Tables. For example 6 x 6. and a PlaceHolder.
I need to place the tables 6 next to each other in the PlaceHolder and then a new line of 6 next to each other, etc. What css properties do I add for each grid to achieve this.
I have

```
LiteralControl ltr = new LiteralControl();
ltr.Text = "<style type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">" + @".fl { float: left}</style>";
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(ltr);

Table[,] tableArray = new Table[6,6];

for (int j = 0; j < tableArray.GetLength(0); j++)
{
    bool first = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableArray.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        if (first)
        {                          
            tableArray[j, i].CssClass = "mGrid";                           
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            tableArray[j, i].CssClass = "fl mGrid";
        }

        tableArray[j, i].Width = Unit.Percentage(100 / 6);
        PlaceHolderTables.Controls.Add(tableArray[j, i]);
    }                    
}
```

But I do not know how to start a new row and then have 5 next to it etc. I am inexperienced with CSS. The tables has been initialised else where. mGrid is defined elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place those 36 tables inside a table with 6x6.

[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LiteralControl ltr = new LiteralControl();
    ltr.Text = "<style type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">" + @".fl { float: left}</style>";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(ltr);

    Table main = new Table();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            Table table = CreateTable($"{i}x{j}");
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Controls.Add(table);
            row.Controls.Add(cell);
        }
        main.Controls.Add(row);
    }
    PlaceHolderTables.Controls.Add(main);
}

private Table CreateTable(string text)
{
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Controls.Add(new Literal {Text = text });

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    return table;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I was not clear in my question. I have created the table ok. I just do not know how to get them on the page 6 in a row. I presume my CSS is wrong. I have a float left at the moment but it is not working.

Comment: Do you want to create 36 tables or a single table with 6 rows x 6 columns?

Comment: I have already created 36 tables but I can not get them in 6 rows of 6 on the page.

Comment: It was not what I was thinking of but it does solve the issue. A good solution.